# Use XPath to match elements whose names are in the format ParentElement.Property when the property is already declared as an attribute of the parent

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, xsd, xpath-1.0

I have an XML file like the following:

```
<Main>
    <Element1 Property1="Hello" Property3="world">
        <Element1.Property2>again</Element1.Property2>
        <Element1.Property3>Dave</Element1.Property3>
    </Element1>
    <Element2 Property1="Hello" Property3="world">
        <Element2.Property2>again</Element2.Property2>
        <Element2.Property1>
            <SpecialElementForSayingHi/>
        </Element2.Property1>
    </Element2>
</Main>
```

I need to match the following elements using XPath - unless there is a way of banning them from existing using a schema, but I don't believe there is:

```
<Element1.Property3>Dave</Element1.Property3>
...
<Element2.Property1>
    <SpecialElementForSayingHi/>
</Element2.Property1>
```

Specifically I need to match all elements where the name of the element is in the format:

```
ParentElementName.NameOfAttributeThatExistsOnTheParentElement
```

I am working in .Net and would rather not use an external library for this, so if this can be achieved using XPath 1.0 that would be ideal. If it is considerably more efficient I would be willing to go with a system that matches the duplicate attribute instead of the element.

**EDIT:** There wasn't actually a question. How do I do this?

Comment: i guess all of the answers here have solved your problem..y not accept one of them if that has solved your problem..it's very **rude** that you dont `acknowledge` others help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to do it with XPAth 1.0 with no success, may be it's possible to do with XPath 2 or XQuery.
In .NET it's better to use LINQ:

```
var xml = @"
    <Main>
         <Element1 Property1=""Hello"" Property3=""world"">
             <Element1.Property2>again</Element1.Property2>
             <Element1.Property3>Dave</Element1.Property3>
         </Element1>
         <Element2 Property1=""Hello"" Property3=""world"">
             <Element2.Property2>again</Element2.Property2>
             <Element2.Property1>
                 <SpecialElementForSayingHi/>
             </Element2.Property1>
         </Element2>
   </Main>";

   var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));

   var result = doc.Root.Descendants().
            Where(x => x.Parent.Attributes().
                                Any(y => x.Name == x.Parent.Name + "." + y.Name)
            );
```

If you want to get string as a result, you can do this

```
   var result = doc.Root.Descendants().
            Where(x => x.Parent.Attributes().
                                Any(y => x.Name == x.Parent.Name + "." + y.Name)
            ).Select(e => e.ToString()).Aggregate((current, next) => current + next);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ2XML`

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");
foreach(XElement elm in doc.Elements())
{
    var attr=elm.Attributes();
     foreach(var elm1 in elm.Elements())
     {
          if(attr.Any(x=>elm1.Name.ToString().EndsWith(x.Name.ToString())) 
              elm1.ToString();//this contains your required XML
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I'm kind of kicking myself for not thinking of it now. I'm going to write up the code and make sure it works before I mark it as the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible to do with XPath 1.0, because it lacks such features as range variables or the ability to specify a function as a location step.

**Here is an XPath 2.0 solution**:

```
/*/*/*
    [substring-before(name(), '.') eq name(..)
   and
     substring-after(name(), '.') = ../@*/name()
    ]
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "/*/*/*
    [substring-before(name(), '.') eq name(..)
   and
     substring-after(name(), '.') = ../@*/name()
    ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transormation is applied against the provided XML document:**

```
<Main>
    <Element1 Property1="Hello" Property3="world">
        <Element1.Property2>again</Element1.Property2>
        <Element1.Property3>Dave</Element1.Property3>
    </Element1>
    <Element2 Property1="Hello" Property3="world">
        <Element2.Property2>again</Element2.Property2>
        <Element2.Property1>
            <SpecialElementForSayingHi/>
        </Element2.Property1>
    </Element2>
</Main>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<Element1.Property3>Dave</Element1.Property3>
<Element2.Property1>
            <SpecialElementForSayingHi/>
        </Element2.Property1>
```

Comment: +1, great work, still in .NET I think it's better to go with LINQ.

Comment: @RomanPekar, You are welcome. There are products like Saxon.NET or XQSharp that are written especially for .NET -- it is natural to use XPath 2.0 with these, under .NET.